# Operator overloading not interchangeable with operands in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, operator-overloading

*I am making a custom number class in flutter and want to do basic arithmetic between the class and normal integers and doubles.*
So I overloaded the multiplication operator in the class definition and tried to use it.
**Example (not of the actual class, but the class implementation important:**

```
class MyClass {
  double value;

  MyClass(this.value);

  MyClass operator *(dynamic other) {
    if (other is num) {
      return MyClass(this.value * other);
    }
    throw ArgumentError("Unsupported operation");
  }
}

void main() {
  MyClass myObject = MyClass(5.0);

  MyClass result1 = myObject * 2;
  MyClass result2 = 2 * myObject;

  print(result1.value); // Expected output: 10.0
  print(result2.value); // Expected output: 10.0
}
```

But what happens in the second case (`2 * myObject`) is I get an error, because you can't add `MyClass` to `num` while you can add `num` to `MyClass`.

**Is there any way to overload the operator so the second case is achievable?**
(Like in C++ you can, for example)

Comment: Smalltalk had this same limitation, and it was solved in the core math classes by using double-dispatch, but even though the object model for Dart was drawn partially from Smalltalk, double dispatch doesn't seem to be used much except in Json parsing.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz so does that mean that I can't do that at all?

Comment: It's not possible in Dart.  Dart does not support *overloading*, so it is not possible to make `num`'s existing operators accept arguments of your type.  You could add your own extensions to `num` so that you do `2.multiply(myObject)` and `myObject.multiply(2)` both work, but IMO it'd probably be best to make `MyClass.operator*` take only `MyClass` arguments and to force callers to wrap `num` values in `MyClass` first.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to overload the operator so that the second case is achievable. You can define a new operator that takes a num as its left operand and a MyClass object as its right operand. Here's an example implementation:

```
class MyClass {
  double value;

  MyClass(this.value);

  MyClass operator *(dynamic other) {
    if (other is num) {
      return MyClass(this.value * other);
    }
    throw ArgumentError("Unsupported operation");
  }

  MyClass operator +(num other) {
    return MyClass(this.value + other);
  }
}

void main() {
  MyClass myObject = MyClass(5.0);

  MyClass result1 = myObject * 2;
  MyClass result2 = 2 + myObject;

  print(result1.value); // Expected output: 10.0
  print(result2.value); // Expected output: 7.0
}
```

In this implementation, we define a new operator `+` that takes a num as its left operand and a MyClass object as its right operand. The implementation simply adds the num to the value of the MyClass object and returns a new MyClass object with the result.

Note that you can define other operators in a similar way to support other arithmetic operations.

Comment: This is incorrect. It doesn't work, because you are still defining the constructor as `MyClass` + `num` and not `num` + `MyClass`.
Did you try to run this code, because I get an error:

`Error: A value of type 'MyClass' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'num'.
 - 'MyClass' is from 'package:dartpad_sample/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
  MyClass result2 = 2 + myObject;`